# How to set a JMS property in WebSphere MQ's rfhutilc?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I need to send a message to a WMQ queue. *RfhUtilc*, a part of *WebSphere MQ Explorer* is the only tool I know. I managed to send a message with the proper text content, but I don't know how to set JMS properties.

With *rfhutilc*, when I browse other messages with JMS properties set correctly, they appear in the "usr" tab as:

```
<propName>value</propName><otherPropName>othervalue</otherPropName>
```

When I try to reverse it — paste such string into the "usr" tab and send the message — I'm not getting any content in this field, when I read the message back. As a result, my message-driven bean doesn't get the message, as its message selector depends on a JMS property.

Anyone knows how to set the properties with *rfhutilc*? Or perhaps suggest a more user-friendly tool that can do it?

Comment: Do you have to you use this tool? Can you not create messages via Java to send to MQ? Then you could gain easy access to the headers to set JMS properties. Or are you thinking more along the lines of settings properties on WebSphere MQ itself?

Comment: @ChrisAldrich No, I don't have to use this particular tool. But I don't want to spend time writing a program doing something that dozens of tools do already, and in a far better way. I just need to trigger my MDB in its target environment to do something.

Comment: Is your WMQ at all visible by a regular WebSphere Application Server instance? Cause if it is, you could potentially use SIBExplorer. Cause you can fool WebSphere into thinking MQ is really SIB messaging and work with the queues that way. We use SIBExplorer here (but we also use SIB messaging, rather than MQ messaging--but that is more to save $$$$).

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Thanks for mentioning the SIBExplorer, I didn't know such tool existed. Too bad it's (temporarily?) unavailable. I will make use of SIB queues, but in a different test environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, rfhutil and rfhutilc are part of [SupportPac IH03](http://ibm.co/SupptPacIH03) and not part of WebSphere MQ Explorer.  The good news with this is that you can download the latest version of IH03 and the User Guide that comes with it.  The User Guide explains that the usr folder if for use with properties stored as RFH2 headers (old V6 style) and that the User Props tab is for V7.  It also provides the syntax for entering name/type/value triplets and a list of available data types.

The User Prop tab is explained beginning on page 41 of the manual (page 56 of the PDF) and the usr tab content begins on page 52 of the manual (page 67 of the PDF).

The page listing all the SupportPacs [is here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  On that page, WebSphere MQ Explorer is [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T).

Comment: Direct, exact, precise. And works. Thank you! I'll only summarize what I've found in the docs: the format for the "usr" tab is "name=value", line by line, datatype markup is also possible.